My Magento SQL is taking 500% of the CPU
I am facing an issue with my SQL database which take 500% of the CPU.
I have taken a screenshot of the process list.
Error:
[2024-06-02T06:00:17.313192+00:00] main.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused [] []


Thank you.

Please consider using SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; in the future for additional helpful information.

Hi, Thank for your reply,
I try to disable module auto relate product,
it gone to normal,
